# Rails to_json static method: TypeError X is not a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, static

I want my to_json to include a static method from a controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base   
  def self.server_time
    Time.now
  end 
end
```

I tried both:

```
o.to_json(:methods => ApplicationController.server_time)
```

And

```
o.to_json(:include => ApplicationController.server_time)
```

But i get **TypeError**:

```
TypeError: 2013-04-04 08:33:31 +0300 is not a symbol
```

*o is an ActiveRecord object*

Comment: sorry, you want a method code or method result to be included?

Comment: @ted Sorry for not being clear. **Method result**, what do you mean by method code?

Comment: `Time.now` serialized (:

Comment: the given answer by xdsemx worked for me as well. Got a json with current time

Comment: and what's `o` in your example?

Comment: @ted The given answer returns the server time as json but i want to serelize my ActiveRecord object (**aka o**) with the server time included, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, my answer didn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno what's `o` in your context, but you can also:

```
[o, ApplicationController.server_time].to_json
```

or

```
{ApplicationController.server_time: o}.to_json
```

to include time in your json

Answer (score 2):

```
ApplicationController.server_time.to_json
```

Works for me

Answer (score 2):

If you want your JSON as before with a new key "time" do this:

```
o.as_json.merge({time:ApplicationController.server_time}).to_json
# => {time:123, id:1, name: 'name', ...}
```

You can also use a key for the time and a key for the object:

```
{time: ApplicationController.server_time, object: o}.to_json
 # => {time:123, object: {id:1, name: 'name', ...} }
```

Thanks to Rails' magic you don't have to specify `to_json` in your controller:

```
render json: o.as_json.merge({time:ApplicationController.server_time})
# or the other option
render json: {time: ApplicationController.server_time, object: o}
```